# "Embed Interop Types" property is missing within Reference Assembly/DLL Property Window of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jenkins, dll, .net-assembly, com-interop

At work, our C# application was developed in a development computer with the following( and our application builds and runs correctly in the development environment):

-.NET Framework 4

-Visual Studio 2010

-ASP.NET Web Forms

At work, we have the following standalone build server that has

-Windows Server 2012

-Jenkins with MS Build

-For .NET Framework 4, the MS Build version is: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>MSBuild.exe -version Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.2558.0 [Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Our standalone back-end SQL Server for the application is:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) Apr 2 2010 15:48:46 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

When we build the application solution on the Jenkins Build server:

> .cs(84,13): error CS1752: Interop type ' ' cannot be embedded. Use the
> applicable interface instead. [ .csproj]   .cs(84,38): error CS1752:
> Interop type ' ' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface
> instead. [ .csproj]   .cs(84,34): error CS0143: The type '  ' has no
> constructors defined [ .csproj]   .cs(85,18): error CS1061: ' ' does
> not contain a definition for 'Set' and no extension method 'Set'
> accepting a first argument of type 'ActiveDs.PathnameClass' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [
> csproj]   .cs(88,17): error CS1752: Interop type ' ' cannot be
> embedded. Use the applicable interface instead. [ csproj]

Therefore, in order to stop the aforementioned error, we wanted to set the "Embed Interop Types" property to  false.

Therefore, I opened up the application solution in question in Visual Studio 2010, but if you look at the picture file below, there is No "Embed Interop Types" property for the assembly in question:

[image]

However, as you can see from the picture, the "Embed Interop Types" property is missing.  Therefore, how do I go about setting the "Embed Interop Types" property to false?

Comment: It is not the only thing that's missing, the `Isolated` property is awol as well.  Fairly typical "make it work on Jenkins" problem.  Restart the battle with the build engineer by deleting the assembly reference and adding it back, using Project > Add Reference, COM tab, tick "Active DS Type library".  Now the Jenkins build will fail again and clarity can ensue.

Comment: Thanks. However, I opened up the corresponding .csproj file within Notepad for the project in question, and then set the "Embed Interop Types" property to false.  But, I still have to test it out on the Jenkins Build Server.